# Is the consumption of bone marrow forbidden?

Tags: food, tanach, eating, blood

Is eating bone marrow the same as eating blood? Do any sources address this issue? Though not the only source I'm interested in, I'd prefer references to the Tanakh, if possible.

Comment: This article discusses whether the bones and liquids in them are kosher even if they come from non-kosher animals. https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/1404/getting-into-continued-on-page-4-the-thick-of-things-gelatin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.71.3?ven=Laws_of_Salting_Meat_--_Rabbi_Ari_Enkin&vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&p2=Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.71.8&vhe2=Torat_Emet_357&lang2=bi) rules it is permitted as long as the bone was salted. A source from Tanakh would be that the Torah specifically forbids breaking the bones of the Paschal lamb, so that one does not draw out the marrow. This does not apply to other sacrifices or non-sacrifices. In fact, the Talmud implies that where not forbidden, eating the marrow would be included in the commandment to eat the sacrifice. See Talmud Bavli Zevachim 97b.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Why would it need to be salted? To remove blood, perhaps? If so, would any other methods of blood removal be permitted, so long as the method gets rid of all the blood?